# xCode Library Paths

Tags: objective-c, xcode, package

I'm starting a new xCode project. I'm porting in some code from my last project, but I've re-ordered the directory structure, so that it makes more sense ala:

```
Lib
  Package1
    File1.h
    File1.m
  Package2
    File2.h
    File2.m
    etc...
```

Now my issue is that before I was using a flat file structure and using the xCode groups to organize, however that isn't ideal.

Now I've re-ordered the directory structure I am referencing the folders instead of using the groups. The problem is now that none of my imports work eg:

```
#import "Lib/Package1/File1.h"
```

It finds the .h file fine, but I'm getting a symbol not found error when ever I reference something that is defined in the .h file.

I'm not sure why the compiler can find the .h file but can't find the symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently referencing the folders doesn't do the same thing as assigning them groups. I re-imported them and choose assign groups instead and the files were added to the target and linked correctly.

It appears to want a flat file structure at least for the project internals. I guess I'll have to manually manage the project internal and the file layouts.